# Will flashing other region's ROM unlock GT-I9515?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, sim-unlocking

I bought a Samsung S4 GT-I9515 from Saudi Arabia. But returning to my country found that this phone is locked and I don not know of any unlock code. It is also not possible to contact the seller in KSA.

Now I'm thinking if flashing stock ROM from other country will solve the issue.

Any help appreciated. Even any known unlocking technique.

Answer (score 1):

Hi flash the phone is not the solution to unlock your device, flash and unlock are different things.

In case you like to flash your phone the only thing that you need to be careful is if the rom that you choose change or replace the modem, in this case you need to check if the rom has the supported bands for your country, The Samsung S4 GT-I9515 supports by hardware the following bands:

#### GSM:

850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz

#### UMTS:

850, 900, 1900, 2100 MHz

#### FDD LTE:

800 (band 20), 850 (band 5), 900 (band 8), 1800 (band 3), 2100 (band 1), 2600 (band 7) MHz

#### Data:

LTE, HSUPA, UMTS, EDGE, GPRS

You could check the bands/networks to your country in this link:

http://www.worldtimezone.com/gsm.html

However if you like to unlock the phone be careful with software methods because you can loss your imei or brick your phone (all software methods need root the phone).

You could check this this link on ebay to unlock your phone, unlock by imei its a more safe solution.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/INSTANT-REMOTE-UNLOCK-FOR-SAMSUNG-GALAXY-S5-G900A-G900T-G900T1-AT-T-TMOBILE-/121748816957?hash=item1c58cb843d

I hope this help you to resolve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ODIN to flash to a non-branded firmware... BUT... The S4 Value does not have an unbranded firmware available.

Go here and pick what country you live in, and flash that firmware via ODIN: http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/1/?model=GT-I9515

This will break KIES updates, but other than that, you'll be golden!

Answer (score 0):

to unlock galaxy s4 i9515, insert a saudi sim  and do outgoing or receive a call for minimum 
5 minutes after that u can insert any country sim without unlock code. I did this and using indian network card.

Answer (score 0):

Also, 
it **might** be possible that you will Need to change the IMEI purposely (Like in Turkey - they filter IMEI Numbers to prevent non-taxed imports) from used domestic phone that is not used anymore - since I don t know what Country you live in. Be VERY careful with flashing Images of different models / countries as it was already said might be different bands etc.)

It does work to unlock by using the SIM Card for 5 Minutes (I think though that the five Minutes Need to be done in the respective Country (carrier))

Answer (score 0):

No flashing another rom/firmware will not unlock the device. put a non SA sim card in the device it well ask for a unlock code which you can buyfrom most phone providers or online